# Sailjs + Angularjs + Yeoman + Grunt can't start angular server

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, sails.js, yeoman

I have an Sailjs (frontend+backend) app that's up and running. However, I would like to separate my frontend(angularjs) and backend(sailsjs). Therefore, I'm trying to follow a tutorial on it: [link](http://okamuuu.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/04/10/135240).

However, it was all smooth until I tried to start the angular server in port 9000 using grunt serve.

```
~/workspace/web/frontend$ grunt serve                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Running "serve" task                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

Running "clean:server" (clean) task                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Cleaning .tmp...OK                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:sass" (wiredep) task                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

    Running "compass:server" (compass) task                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    directory .tmp/styles                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        write .tmp/styles/main.css (4.936s)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

    Done, without errors.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            


    Execution Time (2014-11-10 05:36:51 UTC)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    compass:server  6s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 100%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    Total 6s                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) task                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
File .tmp/styles/main.css created.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

Running "connect:livereload" (connect) task                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Started connect web server on http://localhost:9000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

Running "watch" task                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Waiting...
```

It looks like the server has been started and when I navigate to ~nitrous.io:9000/ it doesn't show anything. However, my sails page is up at ~nitrious.io:1337/ I believe it is suppose to show a yeoman page? I am not familiar with angular + yo + grunt. Is there something that I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have realised that you need to config grunt settings and change the hostname to access it from nitrious io.

```
connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
change this -->hostname: '0.0.0.0',
        livereload: 35729
      },
```

However, I have met with another problem.

```
GET http://nodejs-160326.apse1.nitrousbox.com:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Somehow the script can't seem to load.